# anchor as submit button with resultset value in href

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html><a id="fakeanchor" href="3.jsp?id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>" >id</a>
 </html>

<script>
$("a#fakeanchor").click(function()
    {
    $("#submit_this").submit();
    return false;
    });
 </script>
```

I am trying to replace submit button with anchor tag and also sending resultset value to database jsp.please tell what is going wrong here..

Here is the full jsp page code..

```
    <form method="POST" id="submit_this" action="3.jsp" name="form1">
   <br><br><br><br><br>
    <TABLE border="10"   width="1250">
     <CAPTION><EM>A test table with merged cells</EM></CAPTION>
     <TR><TH rowspan="2">Parameters
    <TH rowspan="2">Excellent <TH rowspan="2">Fair <TH rowspan="2">Good
    <TR><TH>Poor  
     <TR><TH height="100">Presentation Content <TD ><input type="radio" name="r" value="Excellent"/><TD               w         width="150">
     <input type="radio" name="r" value="Fair"/><TD width="100"><input type="radio" name="r" value="Good"/>
     <TD width="100"><input type="radio" name="r" value="Poor"/>
    <TR><TH height="100">Communication and Presentation Skills<TD>
     <input type="radio" name="a"  value="Excellent"/><TD><input type="radio" name="a" value="Fair"/><TD>
    <input  type="radio" name="a" value="Good"/><TD><input type="radio" name="a" value="Poor"/>
     <TR><TH height="100">Depth of Knowledge<TD><input type="radio" name="d" value="Excellent"/><TD>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="Fair"/><TD><input type="radio" name="d" value="Good"/><TD>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="Poor"/>
      <TR><TH height="100">Time utilization<TD><input type="radio" name="i" value="Excellent"/><TD>
      <input type="radio" name="i" value="Fair"/><TD><input type="radio" name="i" value="Good"/><TD>
      <input type="radio" name="i"   value="Poor"/>
  <TR><TH height="100">Involving Audience<TD><input type="radio" name="o" value="Excellent"/>
 <TD><input type="radio"     name="o" value="Fair"/><TD><input type="radio" name="o" value="Good"/>
 <TD><input type="radio" name="o"   value="Poor"/>


 </TABLE>


<br><br><br><br>
 <b><font size="4">Feel Free to add any comments aur suggestions</font></b><br><br>
 <textarea name="text" rows=4 cols=100></textarea>
     <br>
    <br

     <a id="fakeanchor" href="3.jsp?id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>" >id</a>

     </form>

     i am getting an ID number from first.html and showing it on jsp page through

       ResultSet resultset = 
            statement.executeQuery("select * from register where id = '" + id + "'") ; 

        if(!resultset.next()) {

            String site = new String("http://localhost:8888/Feedback/error.html");
            response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
            response.setHeader("Location", site);
        } else {
    %>


    <center><b>
    <font size="4">WELCOME &nbsp; &nbsp;
     <%= resultset.getString(2) %> 

  that ID number should be saved along with the corresponding radio buttons,the user (same ID)clicks on.
  how do i save the resultset value to the database.
  I am sending the resultset value to other jsp which contains my database connections etc. through href.
  .thats why i want this href link to behave same like submit button.
```

.       so that i can send the resultset value to 3.jsp and submit the form as well..

```
    HTML page
    <form method="GET" action="2.jsp" name="form1" target="_blank" onsubmit="setTimeout(function () 
    { window.location.reload(); }, 10)">
     <p>
    <center>
   <b><font size="6">Welcome to the feedback page</font></b>
    </center>
    </p>

     <p align="center"><br><br><br><br>
      <center>ENTER YOUR SAP ID : <input type="text" name="id"/></center><br><br>
     <center><input type="submit"  name=""  value="Submit" onClick="return (verify());"/></center>
     </p>
      </form>
```

Comment: Is `submit_this` a form?

Comment: Why not use a submit button?

Comment: your form id should be `id="submit_this"` and there shouldn't be something with `name="submit"` inside the form and replace the href in your `a` tag, use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: show us full html also

Comment: I'd highly recommend revising your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I guess you want to set `3.jsp?id=..` of your form, so in your function you also need

```
$("a#fakeanchor").click(function()
    {
    $("#submit_this").action($(this).href());
    $("#submit_this").submit();
    return false;
    });
```

This new line I added will put the `href` value of the link in the `action` value of the form.

Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Fwt/2/

Comment: you should `.action` before `.submit`